# Xamarin Android OnOptionsItemSelected async

Tags: c#, listview, asynchronous, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and Android development in general (coming from a Web MVC background) so I am just trying some things out to learn it. Anyway I'm also trying to get better at the async task feature in C# and I seem to have an issue with it.

I have a refresh menu item that when clicked will make a call to a weather API to get the latest info and then I want to update a ListView with that data. I can no problem go out and get the latest data, parse the data, and make the array for the list items. The issue is that no matter how I try to update the adapter or list view nothing ever happens. After debugging and stepping through it it seems as soon as it hits the Clear method for the adapter it just stops debugging and continues running the app (no error message or anything that I can see).

Here is my code for this:

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        var id = item.ItemId;

        // refresh
        if (id == Resource.Id.refresh_weather)
        {
            SetForecastInfo();
        }

        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And this:

```
public async Task SetForecastInfo()
    {
        var task = new FetchWeatherTask();

        var data = await task.ExecuteAsync();

        string[] newData = new string[7];

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            // I make the new strings for the list here
        }

        _listItems = newData;

        _forecastAdapter.Clear();
        _forecastAdapter.AddAll(new List<string>(_listItems));
    }
```

I put a break point on _forecastAdapter.Clear() and inspect all my variables and everything looks perfect and has all the data it needs. Though if I hover over Clear() Visual Studio Debugger says "Unknown Member: Clear" and I press F10 to step over to the next AddAll call and when I do that it just continues on with execution so the AddAll method never gets called. No error message gets printed out to the logs either.

Is this because I can't await SetForecastInfo inside OnOptionsItemSelected? Am I going about this entirely wrong (may very well be, just trying to learn)? any help is appreciated!

PS: The _forecastAdapter works perfectly when the app first loads. It just gets set to static data right now, just trying to get it to update on refresh to test some things out.

Comment: I tried to run your code (just created a simple empty android app) and it runs just fine. Looks like some super strange mono runtime problem (these sometimes happen with xamarin...). Can you provide a compilable and runnable sample of your app for further testing?

Comment: @KaiBrummund yes, I can. I will get that ready right now. I also went and removed all my async task stuff, so when I call SetForecastInfo it would just set it to different static data. When running it like this I now get an exception thrown as soon as it calls clear. Error in log: "[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException' was thrown."

Comment: @KaiBrummund I ended up solving the issue right after I finally got that exception as that finally gave some insight on the issue for me to research. I'll post my answer to answer my own question to hopefully help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by getting rid of all the async stuff and just trying to repopulate it with static data. Doing this gave me `Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException.` After doing some research on why that exception would be thrown on an `ArrayAdapter` I found my answer.

I initially created the ArrayAdapter with a plain static array. When it tried to run the clear method it could not remove the items because of that. Switching to using a collection that allows dynamically removing and adding elements (Like a `List<string>`) when I first initialized the `ArrayAdapter` fixed this. Definitely something I should had caught originally.